# Label the centroid of a polygon in r

Tags: r, coordinates, centroid

I'm currently trying to detect disease clusters in my data and need to extract the centroid of each polygon. When I run;

```
Shape.dat <- as.data.frame(coordinates(FSAShape))   # extract centroids
```

However it returns a list of the centroids without the Name of the polygon. I need to then merge the centroids with my data of diseases, so I need to know which polygon is which so I need to keep the name of the polygon in the output.It currently relabels all the polygon names as a number, not its actual name. I'm worried it might take the centroids in a different order then when I run "unique"!

Please help!
Thanks a million!

Here is what my Polygons are called, and below is the output I get. My file name is "FSAShape"

```
R0G R0H R0J R0K R0L R0M R1B R1N R2C R2E R2G R2H R2J R2K  
R2L R2M R2N R2P R2R R2V R2W R2X R2Y R3A R3B R3C R3E R3G
```

```
           V1         V2
0   -98.08717   49.43897
1   -98.51542   50.34608
2   -100.13448  50.58424
3   -99.73617   49.57764
4   -100.29010  52.00918
5   -100.92629  49.71098
```

```
class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
features    : 6 
extent      : -101.672, -97.09419, 49, 53.01323  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs         : +proj=longlat +datum=NAD83 +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0 
variables   : 6
names       : FSA, PRUID,   PRNAME,   X, Cases, Pop 
min values  : R0G,    46, Manitoba, 597,     0,   2 
max values  : R0M,    46, Manitoba, 598,     0,   5
```

[image: Dput]

Comment: Hi, Holly! It doesn't seem to be a difficult task. However, without having a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your data frame it becomes almost like guessing. Could you please share (at least part) of your data frame?

Comment: @rdornas Thanks for the reply!!! I just added the "head" of the dataset, when I run the "reprex" command it just gives me errors :(

Comment: try to `dput` a sample of your FSAShape so we have some of your data to work with

Comment: @HollyArcher, as @Chris commented, I don't think you'll get an answer without adding part of your data frame. Try `dput`.

Comment: @Chris Hey! I think the "dput" worked! I just posted a picture of what it made :)

Comment: @HollyArcher you can copy and paste the output of `dput` instead of the picture. It should start with `structure(...`. Also just `dput(head(Shape.dat, 10))` not all the data :)